# Expand toggle returns unexpected results JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pop out div at the top of my page, it expands and closes on toggle.

also on toggle i'm giving a different `top position` to a different div ( a pop out side menu)

The problem is the side pop out menu should only pop out on click of the hamburger symbol. For some reason, on click on the top expand div is also opening my side menu.

Can someone see why this is? and what's the most efficient way to stop this ?

**CSS**
this is the css for my side pop out menu

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 96px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f0f1f3f2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.sidenavScrolloff {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f0f1f3f2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.sidenavScroll {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f0f1f3f2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /*transition: 0.5s;*/
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

HTML for my main menu that has a hamburger on click to show my side menu

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <span class="col-3 float-left" id="hamburger-icon" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

    <img class="logo-img-big local-logo-img-big" src="cms-images/logo.png">
</div>
```

Div above main menu that has a expanding div on click (it also opens my side menu, is should not)

```
<a href="#" class="toggle" onclick="dropDownMSG(); this.parentNode.classList.toggle('open');return false;">
    <img src="/Static/images/header-logo-top.png" alt="logo"/>
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

script that controls my side pop out menu and the on scroll function for the side menu plus a function to change the top position of the side menu on expand of the top div

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
    document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "1";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "28";
}

function dropDownMSG() {
    const element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

    if (element.className.indexOf('sidenavScrolloff') === -1) {
        element.className += 'sidenavScrolloff';
    } else {
        element.className = element.className.replace('sidenavScrolloff', '');
    }
}

window.onscroll = function () {onScrollNav()};

function onScrollNav() {
    if (document.getElementById("top-nav") > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenavScroll";
        console.log("you hit 40px !!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").className = "sidenavScrollReset";
        console.log("you back to 0 !!");
    }
}
```

**Problem**

On click of expand menu my side pop out menu also pops out, this should not happen.

Comment: you should use `classList` instead of className. So easy to add/remove/toggle with it.

Comment: Your question is really hard to debug without some working code that shows the actual issue.

Comment: I know, trying to add into a fiddle

Comment: @epascarello found the problem, its the on scroll function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of event bubbling process.

```
function openNav(event) {
         event && event.stopPropagation();
         ....
    }
```

in html

```
<span class="col-3 float-left" id="hamburger-icon" onclick="openNav(event)">&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: thanks ill look into this and accept answer if works

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of toggling multiple class in javascript, hope it will help :

```js
function f() { 
 var element = document.getElementById("btn"); // get the element
 element.classList.toggle("red");  // toggle class red
 element.classList.toggle("blue"); // toggle class blue
}
```

```css
.red { color:red; }
.blue { color:blue; }
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="f()" class="red">color</button>
```